# How to write down the number of the repeated data in R function

Tags: r

Suppose I have repeated simulated data (100 times). Then, suppose that I would like to apply one function on each of these data. Since my data is repeated (sometimes 1000 times) I would like to know at which data my code working at this moment. That is, I would like my code to show the number of each data it is working on it. For example, when my code start with first data, then I would like it to let me know this is the first data. Then, the same for the second data and so on.  I know that I will get the number of my data in console as a list. However, my function is much more complicated. This is just a simple example to explain my problem.  I would like my code to let me know at which data it is working now.

This is my code:

```
  N.a = 186; N.b = 38; N.ab=13; N.o = 284 
## 1) numerical optimization 
llk = function(xpar){ 
    tmp = exp(c(xpar,0))
    pr = tmp/sum(tmp) ## A/B/O 
res1 = N.a*log(pr[1]^2+2*pr[1]*pr[3]) + N.b*log(pr[2]^2+2*pr[2]*pr[3])
res2 = N.ab*log(2*pr[1]*pr[2]) + N.o*log(pr[3]^2)
-res1-res2 
}

pr = rep(1/3,3) ## A/B/O 
it = 0; pdiff = 1 
while( (it<100)&(pdiff>1e-5) ){
    tmp = c(pr[1]^2, 2*pr[1]*pr[3]) 
    tmp = tmp/sum(tmp) 
    N.aa = N.a*tmp[1] 
    N.ao = N.a*tmp[2]
    tmp = c(pr[2]^2, 2*pr[2]*pr[3]) 
    tmp = tmp/sum(tmp) 
    N.bb = N.b*tmp[1]
N.bb = N.b*tmp[1] 
N.bo = N.b*tmp[2] 
pr1 = c(2*N.aa+N.ao+N.ab, 2*N.bb+N.bo+N.ab, N.ao+N.bo+2*N.o)
pr1 = pr1/sum(pr1) 
pdiff = mean(abs(pr1-pr)) 
it = it+1
pr = pr1 
cat(it, pr, "\n")
}
```

How I can use `cat` function. For example, how to use this in my code:

`cat(paste0("data: ", i, "\n"))`

Comment: Is the list numbering itself not enough? Just curious. The result will be outputted as a list. With the list numbering given already

Comment: Yes. I know that. However, my function is iteration for each data. For my code, it shows my (as result) the iteration but I could not know for which data this iteration.

Comment: You will just need to output an `I` on top of whatever you are outputting currently. `lapply(1:100, function(i) list(i,exp(y[[i]])))`

Comment: Have you tried print statements? See `?print` and `?flush.console`.